# Measure Theory Proof that intersection of subset = empty set

Tags: measure-theory

I'm struggling with the following question:

Let H be a subset of $[0,1]$ consiting exactly one representative point from each equivalence class.

Prove that if $q,r \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $q\neq r$ then $(H+q)\cap(H+r)=\emptyset$

I understand that there is an equivalence relation on $[0,1]$ by: $x \sim y$ if and only if $y-x \in \mathbb{Q}$. Apparently this relation partitions the interval $[0,1]$ into a disjoint union of equivalence classes which I don't really understand. I'm assuming I have to somehow show $H+q$ is outside the range of $H+r$.

Comment: Hey there! In general, you should provide details on what you tried, or what avenues you pursued even if they didn't pan out. Otherwise, people around here get real cranky :) https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, sorry I'm new to this. Will edit it now

Comment: No problem at all, I edited my comment with a link to the criteria that will get you the fastest response.

Comment: If you wanted to try a proof by contradiction, what would the first lines be?